# Swipe animation on blackerry

Tags: blackberry

How to make swipe animation on blackberry.
When i swipe the screen, the next information will be shown.
Any sample code is there.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

How about this:

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/23959/Code_sample_Detect_a_swipe_gesture_1426012_11.jsp

Comment: Hi... its for blackberry tablet os?